# Python zip over appending on Dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose input = {a:[1,2,3], b:[4,5,6]}, how would you print the output as {1:4, 2:5, 3:6}.
I tried dictionary comprehension using zip method but it did not work. i also tried using for loops by declaring an empty list and then append it over the values of the dictionary. It worked but not a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
dict(zip(*input.values())
```

The explantation is as follows:

1. `*input.values()` will yield an iterator `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`
2. Then we explode it as arguments of `zip`, so `zip` get `[1, 2, 3]`, and `[4, 5, 6]` as it's arguments.
3. Then `zip` will yield a bunch of tuples, like `(1, 4)`, `(2, 5)`, etc.
4. Finally, `dict` will recognize those tuples as K-V pairs and make a diction (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict).

Answer (score 0):

```
output_dict = {x:y for x, y in zip(input['a'], input['b'])}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?